# DatePicker passing data

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a successful date picker and on the following page a stepper/number picker that allows users to select dates, and item quantities. In a new view, I would like to display all the previous information for them to review. I have a few methods in place but they don't seem to work. I am guessing it is because they aren't textFields, and some extra code is needed in order to ask the UIdatepicker and Stepper to pass the information. Take a look below please :)

Here is my date picker View Controller

```
import UIKit

class StoreDatesViewController: UIViewController {

  
    @IBOutlet weak var nextButton: UIButton!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var dropOff: UITextField!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var pickUp: UITextField!
    
    
    
    
    let datePicker = UIDatePicker()

     override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
        showDatePicker()
         
         
     }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        nextButton.isEnabled = true
    }
    


     func showDatePicker(){
       //Format Date
       datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
         datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .inline
         datePicker.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "yellow-2")
         
         

      //ToolBar
         
   
         
      let toolbar = UIToolbar();
      toolbar.sizeToFit()
         
         let toolbar2 = UIToolbar();
             toolbar2.sizeToFit()
         
      let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(donedatePicker));
         
         
         
     let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(cancelDatePicker));
         
         let doneButton2 = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(donedatePicker2));
            
        let cancelButton2 = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(cancelDatePicker2));

         toolbar.setItems([doneButton,cancelButton], animated: false)
         toolbar.tintColor = .white
         toolbar.backgroundColor = .red
         
    
         toolbar2.setItems([doneButton2,cancelButton2], animated: false)
         toolbar2.tintColor = .white
         
         dropOff.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
         dropOff.inputView = datePicker
         
         pickUp.inputAccessoryView = toolbar2
         pickUp.inputView = datePicker
         
        
}

     @objc func donedatePicker(){

      let formatter = DateFormatter()
      formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
         dropOff.text = formatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
      self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
    
    @objc func donedatePicker2(){

     let formatter = DateFormatter()
     formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
        pickUp.text = formatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
     self.view.endEditing(true)
   }

    @objc func cancelDatePicker(){
       self.view.endEditing(true)
     }
    
    @objc func cancelDatePicker2(){
       self.view.endEditing(true)
     }
    
    @IBAction func didTapNext() {
        let dropOff = dropOff.text
        let pickUp = pickUp.text
        let storeDetailsVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "storeDetailsVC") as! storeDetailsViewController
        storeDetailsVC.dropOff = dropOff!
        storeDetailsVC.pickUp = pickUp!
    }
    
   }
```

Here is my number Pick View Controller

````
import UIKit

class StoreQuantityViewController: UIViewController{
   
   

   @IBOutlet weak var numbers: UILabel!
   
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

   }
   

   @IBAction func stepper(_ sender: UIStepper) {
       numbers.text = String(Int(sender.value))
           
       }
   
   @IBAction func next(_ sender: Any) {
       let data2 = numbers.text
       let storeDetailsVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "storeDetailsVC") as! storeDetailsViewController
       storeDetailsVC.data2 = data2!
       self.navigationController?.pushViewController(storeDetailsVC, animated: true)
       
   }
}
    ```
````

Comment: You can set default values to dropOf and pickUp if this is optional and if this fields are mondatory add validation before sending to confirmation view controller i.e storeDetailsViewController. You can show alert to user to select the dropOf and pickUp first. This way you can pass those information to next controller.

Comment: okok, I understand. How would i write that in code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the information from text fields to Strings in the next View.

Solution 1:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
    pickUp.text = currentDate // This you can create using the date formatter
    dropOff.text = defaultDate // This is default date value you can set if needed
    showDatePicker()        
 }
```

Solution 2:

```
 @IBAction func didTapNext() {
      //Apply validation here to check if its empty if no default value provided.
     if dropOff.text.isEmpty { 
        //Show alert to user to select drof off date.
        return
     }

     if pickUp.text.isEmpty { 
        //Show alert to user to select PickUp date.
        return
     }
     
     let dropOff = dropOff.text
     let pickUp = pickUp.text
     let storeDetailsVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "storeDetailsVC") as! storeDetailsViewController
     storeDetailsVC.dropOff = dropOff!
     storeDetailsVC.pickUp = pickUp!
 }
```